# How to open a file by clicking on HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, hyperlink

I have this table

[image]

I want to click on the link and the file (whatever file) will be opened in a new pop-up window.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="dokumente" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DokuTyp") %>' NavigateUrl='file://<%# Eval("File") %>'></asp:HyperLink></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Description")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Date") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("File") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But it doesn't work with NavigateUrl. Can anyone help me on this or any idea how to do this. Thanks

Comment: You are refering to a column "DokuTyp" which does not exist, according to your screenshot of the table structure. Next: "It doesn't work" is usually the worst error description, I can imagine. Third: Pointing to a server-local file from within a HTTP page, mostly ever is wrong, unless you are using a browser on the server itself.

Comment: what problem or error occurred?

Comment: Uwe: Hi, the column does exist and there's no error though :)

SMK: Hi, there's no problem or error occurred, just nothing happened when I clicked on the link. I think NavigateUrl is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file:/// is for resources on your own machine.

To open files on a server, you will have to link to urls on the server. 
Use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ResolveUrl(pathOnServer);
```

Change your code like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="dokumente" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DokuTyp") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# HttpContext.Current.Request.ResolveUrl(Eval("File")) %>'></asp:HyperLink></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Description")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Date") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("File") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Where Server

Comment: I'm getting error "ResolveUrl is not a member of System.Web.HttpRequest"

Comment: Where are you using it? This is an extension method available for controls.

Answer (score 1):

The "file" protocol opens a file in the user computer.
I guess you have to read the file on the server-side and call a Resposne.Write.

Answer (score 0):

If you want find file on server you can use `Server.MapPath` method; "file://" is not correct url if you want find file on server

```
NavigateUrl=<%#Server.MapPath(DataBinder.Eval("File"))%>
```