# Opening a PDF or Word Document via a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a KnoweldgeBase/Library in which a page lists PDF's and Word Documents associated with the topic selected. These files are uploaded into a folder the URL being "**/Interface/AdminUploads/Miscellaneous/*FILENAME***".

I am listing the files via a table in which each row has an image of the file type, then the file title and then the date published (all created via another page). How can i have the PDF or Word documents opening when i click on the image for the document?

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.

```
            string filepath ="/Interface/AdminUploads/Miscellaneous/FILENAME"; // Full Path of Pdf.
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(filepath);

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);


            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the path in the url of the file.
You need to provide the full path you can ur `Server.MapPath` to get the full path.

Some useful links

1. [How to open a file by clicking on HyperLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245444/how-to-open-a-file-by-clicking-on-hyperlink)

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple code

```
Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.open('{0}','_blank');</script>", "pdflocation/" + "Example.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work via...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@fileLocation);
```

Running this code in a method on image click and passing in the variable 'fileLocation';